# La opcion ----lock-table=false de mysqldump solo evita que las tablas sean modificadas?

Tags: mysql

El siguiente crontab contiene un comando que hace correcto respaldar una base de datos MySql, el detalles es que cuando se está ejecutando, el sitio web que usa la BD pareciera estar bloqueado, no responde, etc, no estoy seguro por que pase esto.

```
30 17 * * * /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump   -h216.70.69.75 -ucountier -pcommx1 countier > /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/respaldo_countier_bd_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S).sql
```

Según leo --lock-table=false evita que las tablas se bloqueen en el momento del respaldo, pero no estoy seguro si eso impide que el sistema use tanta memoria o solo es para que las tablas no puedan ser modificadas en ese momento. También leo que existe el comando -quick pero tampoco estoy seguro si eso sería la solución.

Si alguien sabe un poco más del tema se lo agradeceré